# Places autocomplete search on toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I want to make google search places autocomplete in navigation drawer activity.At the place of toolbar I want to show search autocomplete like google maps app,here is the screenshot showing what I need.Please give me reply...[image]

Comment: see `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter adapter)`

Comment: please give me reply clearly.I got search but I need search screen like above..

Comment: It would be better if you use FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use fragment from Google Place Services.
Here you have example of use this fragment in XML:

```
<fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

This fragment should represent the search bar which you're presenting above. This fragment will perform all the logic of Google Places autocomplete search. Below you have also java usage of this fragment:

```
 PlaceAutocompleteFragment _autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getActivity()
                        .getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        _autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(_placeSelectedListener);
```

And the callback implementation:

```
private PlaceSelectionListener _placeSelectedListener = new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            //Place model has all data about Location selected from search box
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
        }
    };
```

For more information you can check the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete